# How can be setted Console.SetOut(TextWriter) with multi thread C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Assuming I have a multi thread ForEach I would like that every cycle have the Console.WriteLine() converted into a file, the example I have found for mono thread is something like:

```
FileStream ostrm;
StreamWriter writer;
TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;
try
{
     ostrm = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents/Redirect.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
     writer = new StreamWriter(ostrm);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Cannot open Redirect.txt for writing");
     Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
     return;
}
Console.SetOut(writer);
```

Now for multi thread I have try something like:

```
IList<String> testCaseList = ExcelDataAccess.GetTestCases();
Parallel.ForEach(testCaseList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 }, currentTestCase =>`
{
     FileStream ostrm;
     StreamWriter writer;
     TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;
     try
     {
         ostrm = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents/Redirect" + currentTestCase +".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
         writer = new StreamWriter(ostrm);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot open Redirect.txt for writing");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return;
     }
     Console.SetOut(writer);
     Console.WriteLine("Running test: " + currentTestCase);
     //Do some other stuff and some Console.WriteLine();
}
```

But in this way inside every file what is written is not what expected and multi thread looks not handled correctly. How to solve this?

Comment: `Console` is a shared resource; only one thread or task can use it at a time. Adding synchronization wouldn't help because this would just interleave the outputs inappropriately. You simply can't run these test cases in parallel if they use the console. Use an independent `TextWriter`, not the global, shared console -- in other words, make the `writer` a parameter.

Comment: You really need to clean up this code - you're opening disposable resources and never disposing them and you're catching every exception that is possible to be caught. Both are bad practices. Can you please explain what it is that you're trying to do here?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for your reply, understood. I will used TextWriter as suggested. Many thanks.

Comment: @Enigmativity I know the code is not good, is taken from another reply. Anyway what I'm trying to do is to set Console.SetOut(writer); with multithread, but as Jeroen suggested this can't be done.